# How to execute SQL query against input tables in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have four `script component`s in SSIS (set up as sources) that generate four output tables for further procession.

I need some component to allow me to run an SQL command against input tables as if there were tabled in SQL database.

Which component (or a set of components) I should use to query my input and generate output in an aforementioned scenario?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant!

There are a few components that allow you to "check" your data like the row sampling or even the count to count the number of rows, but if you need to run a SQL query on a data set you just read from a text file, you will need to persist your data in a temporary table, do whatever you need to do with it, and then send it to the destination.

If you are on SQL Server 2012, and the query you want to run on the data wont update it, you can use "data taps". What it basically does is send the data passing through a data flow path to a file on the file disk. It is handy but its more of a "debug" mechanism, you dont want to have it on production and rely on it for an important task. They are also  only available when you are executing a package deployed to the SSISDB catalog.